Property `*` does not exist in the provided object
I have a class
export class Player {
  constructor() {}
  play = async (soundUrl: any) => {
    const { sound } = await Audio.Sound.createAsync(soundUrl);
    await sound.playAsync();
  };
  faillure = () => {
    this.play(testFailedSound);
  };

  success = () => {
    this.play(successSound);
  };
  exerciceSuccess = () => {
    this.play(exerciceSuccess);
  };
}

When I try to mock the success method with a spyOn
const successSoundSpy = jest.spyOn(Player.prototype, "success");

I got the error message Property 'success' does not exist in the provided object

I spent at least 3 hours trying to figure out why my code wasn’t working, and it turns out the issue was with how I defined the success function.
I initially used an arrow function:
success = () => {
    this.play(successSound);
  };

But this approach didn’t bind this to the class instance correctly, causing issues when trying to call class methods.
The fix was to change the function to a standard method:
success(){
    this.play(successSound);
  };

This correctly binds this to the class instance, solving the problem.
